# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {<key>}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I want to make a component that will hold a material-ui grid.

There is a codesandbox that I made here: [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-oxqy3)

This is the container component. **AllCards.js**

```
// All the required imports here

const exer = [
  {
    imageurl: "https://media1.giphy.com/media/26tPtg8M3i6DPSSt2/200w.gif",
    imagealt: "react-gif",
    title: "Elongacion de columna",
    body: "Este es un ejercicio que sirve para estirar los lumbares.",
    firstButtonText: "Ver",
    secondButtonText: "Ayuda"
  },
  {
    imageurl: "https://media1.giphy.com/media/26tPtg8M3i6DPSSt2/200w.gif",
    imagealt: "react-gif",
    title: "Elongacion de cuadriceps",
    body: "Este es un ejercicio que sirve para estirar los cuadriceps.",
    firstButtonText: "Ver"
  }
];

function AllCards() {
  const [exercises, setExercises] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setExercises(exer);
  }, [exercises]);

  let ret = exercises ? <CardGrid cards={exercises} /> : null;
  return ret;
}

export default AllCards;
```

And this is the **CardGrid.js** component

```
const CardGrid = props => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { cards } = props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={3} justify="space-evenly" alignItems="center">
        {cards.map((currentCard, ind) => (
          <Grid key={ind} item xs>
            <CardItem card={currentCard} />
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};
```

My **CardItem.js** component

```
const CardItem = props => {

  let ret = null;       
  if (props.card) {
    console.log("ITEM PROPS", props);
    ret = ( <Card . . . )
  // return { ret };     <-- THIS IS WRONG
     return ret          <-- SHOLD BE LIKE THIS
};
```

I have the following error

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {card}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in CardItem (at CardGrid.js:49)
```

**SOLVED:**

In CardItem.js I am returning `{ ret }`

It should be `return ret`

Comment: It looks like you are mutating your `excercise` prop in `CardGrid`, in the initial prop you have is `props.cards`, but later it changes t `props.card`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thomas pointed out, you were importing `CardItem` from the wrong file. Also, inside `CardItem` you were using a prop called `card` but also creating a new variable called `card` to return the component, which causes a naming collision and tries to render an object which is disallowed.

If you change the variable name it seems to work.

Fork [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-b7j9i)

Comment: Hi Chris, I opened you codesanbox and it is not working. I updated my question to show the error I have now.

Comment: It may not have saved, but it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

On your sandbox example, you have `import CardItem from "./CardGrid";` in top of your code within CardGrid.js. I'm assuming that you wanted to say `import CardItem from "./CardItem";`

Then, I believe your component needs to be able to hold ForwardRefs and this guide will help you with that. https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/